# Формула у функции НОРМСТРАСП в Excel, какая?

Tags: python, excel, excel-формулы

> Нeобходимо вычленить формулу из функции "НОРМСТРАСП" в виде текста,
> чтоб можно было воспользоваться ей [в калькуляторе степеней](https://okcalc.com/ru/exponent/) (условно) и для
> последующего использования в программном коде на языке программирования Python. Формула строит стандартное
> нормальное интегральное распределение для передаваемого значения.
>
> Попробовал вычленить согласно формуле, описанной [на сайте
> Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF-463369ea-0345-445d-802a-4ff0d6ce7cac), но почему-то значения не совпадают.
>
> Вот преобразованная в текст формула, которая у меня получилась:

```
(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-1*((z*z)/2))
```

> Если вместо z подставить 1.33333, то должно получиться 0.908788234, но
> почему-то значение получается другое

Comment: это формула *плотности вероятности*... а НОРМСТРАСП вычисляет *функцию распределения*, которая равна *__интегралу__ плотности вероятности* от минуc бесконечночти до `z`... для нормального распределения этот интеграл неберущийся, так что значение этой функции **принципиально** нельзя представить в виде элементарных функций...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, какой-то вы пессимистиичный ответ дали, пусть и верный:-) Полиномиальные интерполяции спрашивающему в помощь!

Comment: @Сергей, я думал упомянуть разложение в ряды, но, понятно, что так ни кто на практике не считает... решил глянуть как оно в glibc [сделано](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/latest/source/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_erf.c) — ад и магия... так что ИМХО единственный здравый подход — это найти встроенную функцию, которая это делает... а т.к. OP не упомянул под какую среду/платформу/язык ему нужно решение, то про пути решения решил вообще не писать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По рекомендации [Сергея](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/489515/), получилось разобраться в данном вопросе. Функция для Python получилась следующая:

```
from math import exp
def normsdist2(z):

    # Защита от переполнения
    if (z > 6.0):
        return 1.0
    elif (z < -6.0):
        return 0.0

    b1 = 0.31938153
    b2 = -0.356563782
    b3 = 1.781477937
    b4 = -1.821255978
    b5 = 1.330274429
    p = 0.2316419
    c2 = 0.3989423

    a=abs(z)
    t = 1.0/(1.0+a*p)
    b = c2*exp((-z)*(z/2.0))
    n = ((((b5*t+b4)*t+b3)*t+b2)*t+b1)*t
    n = 1.0-b*n
    if (z < 0.0):
        n = 1.0-n
    return n
```

Хотя вариант [Fat-Zer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/277616/) даёт более точный результат и имеет компактный вид:

```
from math import erf,sqrt
def normsdist2(z):
    return (1.0+erf(z/sqrt(2.0)))/2.0
```

Comment: если что, на питоне из коробки есть функция ошибки, нормальное распределение через неё механически вычисляется: `(1.0 + math.erf(z / math.sqrt(2.0))) / 2.0`

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft не писал, что это формула и заложена в НОРМСТРАСП:-) Он вам уравнение плотности стандартного нормального распределения привёл, формулу которого и вы тут приводите, а вот считает НОРМСТРАСП функцию нормального распределения.

Вам нужно от этой радости теперь взять интеграл.
Вот вам в помощь ссылка: https://smart-lab.ru/blog/213739.php, там ещё ряд ссылочек внутри на коды.

(Сразу почувствовал, что формула странновата, но минут 40 убил, чтобы вспомнить, почему, да поискать подтверждение:-))

Comment: Благодарю, что подсказали, спасибо за ответ. Мне нужно было интегрировать это в Python

Comment: Александр, спасибо за обратную связь:-) Каким образом получилось - в ваш комментарий не попало, к сожалению. Если считаете, что ответ решил задачу - можно принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева). Или свой поместить, если собирались так.

Comment: Решение добавил отдельным ответом

Comment: Спасибо! Успеха в статистике:-)